# How to disable elasticsearch http module?

Tags: elasticsearch

The default value of "http.enabled" option in elasticsearch's configuration file is true which means that we can search and admin the cluster from http command, for example:DELETE /index_* request can delete all indexes. But this is not safe when deployment the service to the production environment. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either implement [shield](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/shield/) - this is free if you are paying for one of the Elasticsearch support packages.

Or implement a reverse proxy which checks each request and the user running the request, for example [nginx](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/playing-http-tricks-nginx/).